# How to tell Finder where to find private key when "Connect to Server" using SSH?

Tags: network, finder, macos, ssh

In Finder, using the *Connect to Server* option, I am able to specify the server I wish to connect to using `ssh://user@server` form (hostname or IP).  However, the server I'm connecting to requires public key authentication, thus Finder,when I press the *connect* button, responds in a new window:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
[Process completed]
```

How do I configure Finder to be able to locate my private key in ~/.ssh?

macOS Sierra 10.12.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finder in macOS Sierra appears to only add the id_rsa key by default.
If you want to add other keys you either have to add them manually or alter the configuration.

on my machine a simple `ssh-add ~/.ssh/test.key` worked.

[According to this guide you can also store the keys in your keychain](https://github.com/jirsbek/SSH-keys-in-macOS-Sierra-keychain):

In ~/.ssh create config file with the following content:

```
Host * (asterisk for all hosts or add specific host)
  AddKeysToAgent yes
  UseKeychain yes
  IdentityFile <key> (e.g. ~/.ssh/userKey)
```

[You can read more about this on the Apple Developer Site](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2449/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40017589)

Comment: Whilst this worked, it did not open the server in Finder, which was my objective as I'm able to connect to the server from a terminal using SSH.

Comment: @gone to my knowledge this is not possible since Finder only Supports FTP. If you want to actually mount SFTP in Finder, try SSHFS or a GUI variant like macfusionapp.org

Answer (score 1):

You have to add your public key (e.g. ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) to the authorized_keys file on the server. If you have no key/public key create one with:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "user@host" #-C "user@host" is an optional comment
```

If you have no access to the server you have to provide the public key to an admin and ask him to add it to the authorized_keys file on the server.

---

Creating a config file as proposed in rwenz3l's answer is not required when you didn't enter a passphrase for the rsa key.